# How to requeue a mbox file with sendmail

Tags: queue, sendmail, maildir

A bad change in sendmail has generated mailbox files instead of writing emails in maildir.
We have roll-backed the change and emails are now well delivered in mailboxes.
But, emails in mailbox files remain, and I am looking for a way to requeue those emails, so that they can be deliver into maildir.

Comment: Hi. I am reviewing your post. Your question is good, but to help the community help you, it is always a good idea to add some code.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but it is a general question, so need to add specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used **mb2md** (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/mb2md.1.html) to convert all those mailboxes to maildirs, then copied different emails inside new created maildirs to respective users maildirs.

Script looks like this code :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd  /var/spool/mail/
for dir in $( ls ); do
/root/bin/mb2md -s /var/spool/mail/$dir -R -d /root/tmp/$dir
sleep 60
chown $dir.users /root/tmp/$dir/cur/*
chmod 600 /root/tmp/$dir/cur/*
sleep 60
dir2=$(getent passwd $dir |awk -F: '{print $6}')
echo "cp -a /root/tmp/$dir/cur/*  $dir2/Maildir/new/"
cp -av /root/tmp/$dir/cur/*  $dir2/Maildir/new/
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is described there : http://giantdorks.org/alain/resend-mail-thats-locally-stored-in-a-mbox-format-on-a-linux-box-to-a-working-email-address/

It uses formail to detach emails and sendmail to resend them.